# How do login and register with other custom table in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am making a custom login in Laravel 7. Register is done correctly but login is not working properly. What can i do for login using custom table user_master.
My database table is user_masters.

**User_master model**:

```
<?php   
    namespace App;       
    
    use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    class User_master extends Model implements Authenticatable
    {
        //
        use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
        
        protected $fillable = [
            'user_full_name', 'user_email', 'user_password','user_otp_code','user_phone'
        ];

        protected $hidden = [
            'user_password'
        ];
    
        protected $casts = [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
    }
```

This my controller. what have I done wrong here?

```
<?php

// namespace App\Http\Controllers;
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;  
use App\User_master; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Validator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserMasterController extends Controller
{
    //
    public $successStatus = 200;

    /** 
     * login api 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function login(){ 
        if(Auth::attempt(['user_full_name' => request('user_full_name')])){ 
            $user = Auth::user_master(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
        } 
        else{ 
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
        } 
    }
    /** 
     * Register api 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function register(Request $request) 
    { 
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'user_full_name' => 'required', 
            'user_email' => 'required|email', 
            'user_password' => 'required', 
            'c_password' => 'required|same:user_password', 
        ]);
if ($validator->fails()) { 
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
        }
$input = $request->all(); 
        $input['user_password'] = bcrypt($input['user_password']); 
        $user = user_master::create($input); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        $success['user_full_name'] =  $user->user_full_name;
return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this-> successStatus); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have your custom controller and views, just change the routes to your desired paths. For example, in the login controller, point to the `User_master`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your authentication driver properly to work with your custom user Model.

Make these configuration in `config/auth.php` file ,in `providers` section:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User_master::class, // <---- Your custom user model
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

### Notice:

1. You must implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface.
2. `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` is a class, you cannot implement it.

Comment: Now this is error its givingSymfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: App\User_master cannot implement Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User - it is not an interface in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Latest\CoDee\app\User_master.php on line 11

Comment: @RaviRanjan Refer to notices that I've added in the answer